# convert BYTE* to wstring?

Tags: c++

Hi how to convert BYTE* to wstring?

I googled it, but I could find it nowhere.

```
BYTE* value = new BYTE[size];
wstring wstr;
```

I want to assign value to wstr. How to do it ?

Comment: What encoding is your byte array in? Is it already suitable for putting in a `wstring`? That is: is it UTF-16 (on Windows) or UTF32 (others)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your byte array is UTF-16 encoded, you can simply cast the buffer to `wchar_t*` and pass that to the string's constructor:

```
wstring wstr(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(value), size/sizeof(wchar_t));
```

If the buffer contains a null-terminator you'd need to subtract that from the length passed to the constructor.

Comment: Heffrnan, Actually, the "value" is returned from the registry. RegQueryValueEx function is called and "value" is populated. Then is it a null terminated BYTE string ?

Comment: It's usually null-terminated, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Can I assign to wstring with out using constructor since we have already declared the string.

Comment: Sure. You can use the `assign` member function: `wstr.assign(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(value), size/sizeof(wchar_t))`.